# What happens to unassigned `Eigen::VectorXd` object following a call to `segment()`?

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I have a class `Foo` that stores Eigen `MatrixXd` and `VectorXd` of matching dimensions and offers a simple function `.mult()` that performs matrix-vector multiplication. And I have a function that calls `mult()`, takes a segment of the returned vector, and does some further computation. Here is a simplified version of the code:

```cpp
#include <Eigen/Dense>

class Foo {
  Eigen::MatrixXd X;
  Eigen::VectorXd v;
public:
  Foo() {
    X.resize(2, 2);
    v.resize(2);
    X << 1, 4, 2, 4;
    v << -1, 1;
  }
  Eigen::VectorXd mult() {
    return X * v;
  }
};

Eigen::VectorXd bar() {
  Foo f;
  Eigen::VectorXd val = f.mult().segment(1, 1);
// Use val to do some computation.
  Eigen::VectorXd ret = val.array() + 2;
  return ret;
}
```

During a code review, a comment was raised that this could lead to dangling reference of the unnamed/temp variable that stores the result of `f.mult()`. And a general question was raised regarding the lifetime of temporary variables that aren't assigned a name.

If I understand RVO correctly, a temporary object will be created on the stack whose address will be passed to `f.mult()`, which will then store the result of  `X * v` to the passed in memory address. And this temporary object will go out of scope when `bar()` terminates. There shouldn't be any dangling reference or concerns regarding the scope of the temporary and unassigned variable. But I'm not so sure.

Eigen is an elegant but a complex library and I hope to ensure that I'm using it in safely as possible. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where do you think a dangling reference could occur? This seems to be more of a general C++ rather than an Eigen question. If you concern is about expression templates: Since you are returning/assigning to `Eigen::VectorXd` all expressions get evaluated.

Comment: Expression templates aside, a good rule of thumb is "temporaries go out of scope at the next semicolumn". RVO or not,  your code is safe because the assignment to `val` appens before the semicolumn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is save (but inefficient).

`f.mult()` returns a `Eigen::VectorXd` object by value which exist for the rest of the statement ("until the next `;`"). So calling `segment()` on it is safe, as long as you store that result into a `VectorXd` (and not into an `auto` object).

To get a segment of a matrix-vector product it would however be more efficient to just multipy the corresponding sub-block of the matrix, i.e.:

```
(X*v).segment(a,b) == X.rows(a,b) * v
```